# Powershell - The term 'New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey' is not recognized - trying to create Column Encryption Key

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-powershell, always-encrypted

I'm using Powershell 7.0.3.
Having connected to azure (via connect-AzAccount) I can list my Column Master Keys:

```
Get-SqlColumnMasterKey -InputObject $database

Name
----
MYDB_CMK
MYDB_CMK2
```

On attempting to create a Column Encryption Key..

```
New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey -Name "MYDB_CEK" -InputObject $database -ColumnMasterKey "MYDB_CMK"
```

I get the following error:

```
New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey: The term 'New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

As far as I'm aware the commands **Get-SqlColumnMasterKey** and **New-SqlColumnEncryptionKey** should be in the same module, loaded via

```
Import-Module "SqlServer"
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Might be a versioning issue -- the docs are horrid at documenting what version includes what (in practice, it depends on OS version, PowerShell version *and* module version). On my system I have this cmdlet and version 21.1.1879 of the module, for example. Try `Get-Module SqlServer` after importing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 2023 Update

The `SqlServer` module in Powershell 7.x (v 22+) now supports all of the Sql Column Encryption cmdlets as per the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/new-sqlcolumnencryptionkey?view=sqlserver-ps

[image]

## Original answer

Yes, it is a part of `SqlServer` module but, it is only supported in Powershell 5:

[image]

Comment: Thanks singhh-msft. This is somewhat beguiling as I moved to Powershell 7 since something didn't work in 5, and now my 7 scripts don't work in 5 either. Hey ho it's what makes IT so... exciting :D Cheers.